# C# Generic Method Declaration

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a problem with the signature of generic method that I am trying to create.

The class is as follows:

```
public class MarketDataRepository : IRepository
{
    MarketWatchEntities _dbContext = new MarketWatchEntities();

    public MarketDataRepository(){}

    public MarketDataRepository(MarketWatchEntities dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetMarketData<T>(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime ) where T : MarketDataPoint
    {
        return _dbContext.MarketDataPoints.Where(x => x.ReferenceDateTime >= startDateTime && x.ReferenceDateTime <= endDateTime).ToList();
    }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetMarketData<T>(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime) where T : MarketDataPoint;
}
```

Additional information:

`MarketWatchEntities` extends `DbContext` (generated by Entity Framework).

I get this compile time exception:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MarketWatcher.Domain.MarketDataPoint>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I was expecting this to be OK on the basis that I'm constraining `T` to be inherited from `MarketDataPoint`. So, I thought I would be able to return an `IEnumerable` of `MarketDataPoint`.

Any pointers as to what is wrong with the above and what I should do instead would be hugely appreciated!

**Solution** (Thanks Everyone):

```
public class MarketDataMarketDataRepository : IMarketDataRepository
{
    MarketWatchEntities _dbContext = new MarketWatchEntities();

    public MarketDataMarketDataRepository(){}

    public MarketDataMarketDataRepository(MarketWatchEntities dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetMarketData<T>(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime ) where T : MarketDataPoint
    {
        return _dbContext.MarketDataPoints.Where(x => x.ReferenceDateTime >= startDateTime && x.ReferenceDateTime <= endDateTime).OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put the GetMarketData<T> Method into your IRepository Interface at all? Smells like a break in your design

Comment: You're absoultely right. This will be end up as IMarketDataRepository the extends from IRepostory.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this doesn't work is because `T` can be *more specific* than `MarketDataPoint`.

If you have class `S` that derives from `MarketDataPoint` and someone calls `GetMarketData<S>`, how can you give them an `IEnumerable<S>` when all you have is a collection of `MarketDataPoint`s?

EDIT: As Matt himself points out, you can chain a call to `OfType<T>()` that will weed out the non-`T` elements *and* return the correct type of `IEnumerable`.

```
return _dbContext.MarketDataPoints
    .Where(
        x => x.ReferenceDateTime >= startDateTime &&
        x.ReferenceDateTime <= endDateTime)
    .OfType<T>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. I think that I may need to extend this method later on to use typeof(T) so I wanted to get the declaration right up front but for now I can do as you suggest.

Comment: @Matt My first answer was mistaken and I've changed it, but for now if you only have `MarketDataPoint`s to deal with then just make the method non-generic.

Comment: @Rawling: By checking if the element in the table is of type T or IsAssigableFrom(typeof(T)). This way, this method would always return the requested type T and filter out the wrong types.

Comment: @Rawling: Thanks for the clarification. That seems obvious now that you've explained it ;-) I Guess that the best bet here is to select market data points that are of type S and then cast the list to IEnumerable<S>?

Comment: @Matt Yes, there's the `OfType<T>()` method that can do this for you, I'd forgotten about that :)

Comment: @Rawling: You can remove ToList() as OfType() already return a IEnumerable

Comment: I've updated the question with the final working class incorporating all the correct coments so far. Thanks very much everyone.

Comment: @LightStriker I assumed he wanted to execute the query and pull the data from the database, although I usually detest unnecessary `ToList` calls too :)

Answer (score 0):

And if you follow the error and manually cast it `IEnumerable<T>`?

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMarketData<T>(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime) where T : MarketDataPoint
{
    return (IEnumerable<T>)_dbContext.MarketDataPoints.Where(x => x.ReferenceDateTime >= startDateTime && x.ReferenceDateTime <= endDateTime).ToList();
}
```

The problem is that `IEnumerable<MarketDataPoint>` is not the same as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes - This works. Thanks, Not sure why I didn't think of that ;-)

Comment: @LightStriker If you call this with something _derived from_ `MarketDataPoint` as `T`, this will fail at runtime. (I've not DV'd you as I made this same mistake myself!)

Comment: @Rawling: Yes... That's why I would add some type check in there, but without knowing the expected design that would derive of MarketDataPoint or exactly what he is expecting from that, there is no way to formulate a full bullet-proof answer.